# Partial Frac. Decomp. I tried both B and Bx+C. Which is correct?

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

***Disclaimer: I am not a student trying to get free internet homework help. I am an adult who is learning Calculus. I am deeply grateful to the members of this community for their time.***

I am not sure why you need to use B vs. Bx+C.  I tried both, and got 2 different answers.  In the past, the only explanation I got to why you need to use Bx+C is that just using B would not give an answer.  Well, this time both ways yielded an answer.  Why is one incorrect??

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible,
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Moo, let me look now.  You're saying there is a computational mistake in the 2nd one?

Comment: You're talking about doing a check, correct ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I went through the 2nd problems calculations (as written, not the check) and do not see anything wrong.  Even if the combining does not work, how am I supposed to know to check it?   I got B = 1, and there is nothing to indicate it does not work.   I've not heard that you need to check/verify every fraction decomp. you do, so this is very frustrating.  I do not see any mistake, and do not see why I need to do a check to find a mistake.

Comment: Do you see the line above the cross outs?  (3rd line, in 2nd problem)   See the side note?  I let x=1, and I get A = -1.   I did not use the matching coefficients method.  So, we have conflicting A values.  Why is my method wrong?

Comment: But, that is the way you solve these problems.  You sub in any value  of x you want.  Typically, it is the one that cancels out one of the terms.  For example, if you have $7 = A(x-1) + B(x-2)$,   you let x=1, which cancels out the A term, and you can then solve for B with $7=B(1-2)$

Comment: ie:  The constant A and B do not change values for different x values.  They are constants.

Comment: Why did @moo erase all his answers ?

Answer (score 1):

A simple sanity check shows that your second solution is incorrect:
$$\frac{1}{x^2+x+1} - \frac{1}{x-1} = \frac{x-1 - x^2 -x - 1}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)} = \frac{-x^2-2}{x^3-1}\neq \frac{x^2-2x-2}{x^3-1}$$

It is easiest to explain why your second approach does not work using the language of linear algebra. Let $P_2(\Bbb R)$ be the vector space of all polynomials of degree $\leq 2$. In addition, let:
$$f(x) = x^2+x+1$$
$$g(x) = x - 1$$
$$h(x) = x^2 - x$$
In your second approach, you are attempting to find a linear combination of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that yields $x^2-2x-2$. But this is impossible because $x^2-2x-2$ is not in the span of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Thus, there are no constants $A,B$ such that $Af + Bg = x^2 - 2x - 2$. Using $Bx+C$ instead of $B$ works because it will give you *three* polynomials that span all of $P_2(\Bbb R)$ (from your first approach, you can see that these polynomials are $f(x)$, $g(x)$, and $h(x)$). Hence, you are guaranteed to be able to find constants $A,B,C$ such that $Af + Bg + Ch = x^2-2x-2$.

---

Note also that when you solved for $A,B$ in your second approach, you were essentially constructing a parabola that matches $x^2-2x-2$ on exactly two points. There are infinitely many such parabolas. A parabola is uniquely defined by *three* points, so if you want to make sure that whatever you are solving for ends up being equal to $x^2-2x-2$, you must confirm that there are three points that both of them pass through. Obviously, you cannot force that to happen using your second approach, since $A(x^2+x+1) + B(x-1)$ can be completely defined using only two points. So that approach will fail most of the time.

Comment: Whoa, you're on a whole different level.  I sort of see what you mean, barely.  My question is how can you know that the A & B combination can never result in the 2x term?   You can't know this ahead of time, so where does the general RULE come from?   Like the other response, you are still just checking the incorrect result.   How do we know that using A & B will fail ahead of time?  (and not A & Bx+C)

Comment: No. The only part of my answer checking your incorrect result is the first two lines. The rest was trying to give you an idea of why using only $A$ and $B$ will fail most of the time, using your specific problem as an example. Do you know what "vector space", "linear combination", and "span" mean?

Comment: Not really.   So, I just need to know ahead of time that B over an $x^2$ term on the bottom is simply never going to work?  It's too bad, since there is no way to tell while doing the problem.

Comment: @JackOfAll It will _almost never_ work. A "linear combination" of two polynomials $f,g$ is just a sum of multiples of $f$ and $g$ (e.g., $3f+2g$). The polynomials of degree $\leq 2$ form a $3$-dimensional space. Linear combinations of any two polynomials $f,g$ in that space form a $1$ or $2$-dimensional subspace. Obviously, most polynomials with degree $\leq 2$ will not be in that subspace. So the chances of you being able to find a linear combination of $f,g$ that is equal to some polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ is pretty much zero. That is why using $A,B$ instead of $A, Bx+C$ does not work.

Comment: @JackOfAll To address your first comment, if you want a **general** rule, you may read my answer, which *doesn't* borrow any vocabulary in linear algebra (vector space, span, etc).  Instead, I *extend* a trick that you applied to a larger algebraic structure.

Comment: @JackOfAll If you are familiar with complex numbers (and I hope you are at this point) then GNU Supporter's answer will be the easiest to understand.

Answer (score 0):

> Why you need to use $Bx+C$ instead of just using $B$?

Since you know the trick of "let $x=1$" to find coefficient $A$ in  $\dfrac{A}{x-1}$, I'll give you another answer (for fun) using the *same* substitution trick, but applied on each complex root $r_i$ of the denominator $Q(z)$.

*It would be more instructive to work on a general setting, so that calculation mistakes won't hinder you from getting the whole idea.*

To find $A_i$ in $\require{action}$

$$\bbox[5pt, border: 1pt solid red]
{\toggle
{\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)} = \sum_{j = 1}^{\deg Q} \frac{A_j}{z-r_j}, \\
\bbox[3pt]{\text{Click to multiply it by } z-r_i}}
{\frac{P(z)}{\displaystyle \prod\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j\ne i}}^{\deg Q} (z-r_j)}
= A_i + \sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j\ne i}}^{\deg Q} \frac{A_j}{z-r_j} (z-r_i),}
\endtoggle}
$$

we substitute $r_i$ into the above clicked equality, so that

$$\bbox[4pt, border: 1pt solid blue]{
A_i = \frac{P(r_i)}{\displaystyle \prod\limits_{\substack{j=1 \\ j\ne i}}^{\deg Q} (r_i-r_j)}.
} \tag{*} \label1$$

**If $Q$ has *real coefficients*, the complex roots of $Q$ must occur in conjugate pair(s), so you may add up the corresponding terms to see why you need $Bx+C$ instead of $B$ in the denominator.**

$$\frac{A_k}{z-r} + \frac{A_\ell}{z-\bar{r}} = \toggle
{\frac{\mbox{degree one polynomial in } z}{\mbox{degree two polynomial in } z}}
{\frac{(A_k+A_\ell)z - A_k \bar{r} - A_\ell r}{z^2 - 2 \mathrm{Re}(r)z + 
|r|^2}}
\endtoggle \tag{click for details}$$

> Well, this time both ways yielded an answer. Wh[ich] is one incorrect?

Looking at the degree of real factors of the denominator $Q(x)$, we know that the second approach is *incorrect*.

Exercise: Calculate $A$ in the question body using \eqref{1}.

> Let $\omega$ be the 3<sup>rd</sup> root of unity.  $Q(x) = x^3-1 = (x-1)(x-\omega)(x-\omega^2)$.  Note that $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$, $\omega^2 = \bar{\omega}$ and $\omega^3=1$.  Let $\beta$ and $\gamma$ correspond to $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ respectively.  \begin{align} A &= \frac{1-2-2}{1+1+1} = -1 \\ \beta &= \frac{\omega^2 - 2\omega - 2}{(\omega-1)(\omega-\omega^2)} \\ &= \frac{-\omega-1 - 2\omega - 2}{-\omega^3 + 2\omega^2 - \omega} \\ &= \frac{-3\omega-3}{-1 + 2(-\omega-1) - \omega} = 1  \\ \gamma &= \frac{\bar\omega^2 - 2\bar\omega - 2}{(\bar\omega-1)(\bar\omega-\omega)} \\ &= \frac{\overline{{\omega^2 - 2\omega - 2}}}{\overline{(\omega-1)(\omega-\omega^2)}} = \bar\beta = 1 \end{align} \begin{align} \frac{Bx+C}{x^2+x+1} &= \frac{\beta}{x-\omega} + \frac{\gamma}{x-\omega^2} = \frac{2x-\omega-\omega^2}{x^2+x+1} = \frac{2x+1}{x^2+x+1} \end{align}